# Panelgrid rendered property in JSF

Tags: jsf, richfaces

in a composite component I have this piece of code

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="bean" required="true"/>
    <composite:attribute name="selectable" required="true"/>
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
............

<h:panelGrid rendered="#{cc.attrs.selectable}"> 
    <h:column styleClass="colonneCheckbox">
        <center><h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{liste.selected}" /></center>
    </h:column>
</h:panelGrid>  

.............

</composite:implementation>

</html>
```

And I call it this way :

```
<ccc:resultatRechercheClient bean="#{rechercheClient}" selectable="true"/>
```

However the panegrid is not rendered, is it because the only way to activate it is to create a boolean variable inside the bean, set it to true and then pass it as a parameter?

something like this :

```
<ccc:resultatRechercheClient bean="#{rechercheClient}" selectable="#{rechercheClient.render}"/>
```

thanks

Comment: This might not work because the panelgrid is inside a richfaces component

Comment: You can use `selectable="#{true}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<h:panelGrid>` doesn't support `<h:column>` at all. Use `<h:panelGroup>` instead.

```
<h:panelGrid rendered="#{cc.attrs.selectable}"> 
    <h:panelGroup styleClass="colonneCheckbox">
        <center><h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{liste.selected}" /></center>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGrid>
```

By the way, the HTML `<center>` element is deprecated since 1998. Use CSS for styling and positioning and make sure that you learn HTML based on up to date resources.